# Given just the front end how do I navigate to the related code.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, frontend

I am given a front end page. I can inspect it using chrome or firefox. Can I navigate from the front end to see the corresponding source code. I am working on Ruby on Rails. I am not posting any code because it is corporate code. If you need any information please ask me and I will provide it.

Comment: What source code you are referring to? Could you provide an example?

Comment: @Stefan  Im talking about the corresponding Javascript code

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, can you provide an example, please?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no.

The browser never knows what happens behind the scenes. Ruby only sends the html output that the code generates, there's no source code transmitted to the browser at all.